# GAE Restful Web Service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, rest

I want to develop restful web service in java for google app engine. the tools i am using are

```
Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 (Build id: 20140224-0627)
Google AppEngine Java SDK 1.9.2
```

i have used many versions of Jersey, e.g. 1.8, 1.5 etc. if i run the project on local server it works fine but when i deploy it on the google app engine i can able to open the welcome web page but can't able to access web service.

as mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava link, GAE support Jersey 1.5 but when i import those jars files in my project i can't able to deploy it on GAE.

i don't know which version of Jersey should i use with
    Google AppEngine Java SDK 1.9.2
or should i use another version of SDK.

my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <display-name>com.cit.cittracker</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Sample Web Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.cit.cittracker</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name> 
            <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Sample Web Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my webservice class

```
package com.aakib.sample;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/hello")
public class SampleHello {

    /*This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is requested*/
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey" + "(In Text Format)";
    }

    /*This method is called if XML is requested*/
    @GET  
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello>Hello Jersey</hello>"
                                            + "<format>XML</format>";  
    }

    /*This method is called if HTML is requested*/
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</h1><h2>In HTML Format<h2></body>" + "</html> ";
    }

    /*This method is called if HTML is requested and have two parameters*/
    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHelloWith1Param(@PathParam("name") String vName) {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>Hello " + vName + "</h1><h2>In HTML Format</h2>" + 
                "<h3>1 Value Passed</h3>" + "</body>" + "</html> ";
    }

    /*This method is called if HTML is requested and have two parameters*/
    @GET
    @Path("{name}/{surname}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHelloWith2Param(@PathParam("name") String vName, @PathParam("surname") String vSurname) {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>Hello " + vName + " " + vSurname + "</h1><h2>In HTML Format</h2>" + 
                    "<h3>2 Value Passed</h3>" + "</body>" + "</html> ";
    }
}
```

when i tried with Jersey 2.5 & Jersey 1.17 i got the error on local server as

```
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:45 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:47 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed B:\Programming\Java EE\CIT Tracker Web Service\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:47 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed B:\Programming\Java EE\CIT Tracker Web Service\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:47 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google AppEngine Java SDK 1.9.2\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'B:\Programming\Java EE\CIT Tracker Web Service\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:47 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:47 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.cit.cittracker
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed CIT Tracker WebService: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7adb5354{/,B:\Programming\Java EE\CIT Tracker Web Service\war}: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@4c73cedb: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)

Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Apr 12, 2014 2:10:48 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

and when i try to open in browser it says

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: What error do you get in logs when you try to access the web service?

Comment: Also, try the latest version of Jersey: 1.18

Comment: maybe the server had not warmed up for some reasons. This may happens. There are some differences between local and production server. Check the logs and especially warm up requests. Then check if you have your instances alive. Maybe you have exceeded a free version limits. BTW The latest version of Jersey is 2.7. But to be safe please use 2.5. The newest one had some issues with cashing and without fixing may not work properly or not work at all :P

Comment: Jersey 1.18 is not working. now i will try with Jersey 2.5.

Comment: i tried with Jersey 1.17 & 2.5 but no luck. i edited my question with error log

Answer (score 0):

I used `Jersey 1.18` with `Google App Engine SDK 1.8.8` without problems. Try to use these versions end everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

shoud be the clue - though it isn't too helpful, it perhaps implies that somewhere on your classpath the application has managed to load a class and its interface but they are incompatible.

A little higher up in the error log:

```
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7adb5354{/,B:\Programming\Java EE\CIT Tracker Web Service\war}: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

looks like it is using a path on a local windows drive, with a space in it - don't use spaces in your paths, Microsoft allowed it from Windows95 and it's caused problems ever since, and don't specify a path to your local drive on deployment - it needs to be application-relative.

Hope this helps, sorry to not be more specific.