# Google App Engine: supported frameworks for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Where can i find the list of technologies/frameworks that are supported/works with Google App Engine?

Previously, there was a list maintained [at this link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) which now throws a "404: Not Found".

The source [for this wiki](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/wiki/WillItPlayInJava.wiki?r=150) has not been updated in a while.

The above link has been quoted in many GAE related question in StackOverflow as part of the answer like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893738/google-app-engine-java-frameworks). Others have been resorting to [trial and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968539/gae-restful-web-service-in-java) to find out the supported version of different frameworks.

Is there an official list maintained by the Google App Engine/Cloud folks? If not, are there any unofficial list/pointers?

Comment: It is unfortunate that no one supports this list anymore - it was useful. Meanwhile, you can ask the community here about the frameworks you are considering - some people must have experience with them and be able to help.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid exactly that. It seems to be a waste of developer time having to make decisions based on trial and error/forums.

Comment: You should ask more specific, what framework you need to integrate with GAE. By the way, I successfully integrated spring MVC and spring security to GAE. Hibernate is applied only for RDB so I think it's suitable for Google cloud sql, you can also use JPA or JDO API to manipulate with NoSql db